# Method and/or KFunction to KSFunctionDeclaration

Tags: kotlin, reflection

What is the most reliable way of getting KSFunctionDeclaration(from kotlin source processor framework) instance from Method/KFunction instances? Specially if there is several overloads, and I need to get exactly one that matches by signature.